# Similarity of words using BERTMODEL

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, similarity, bert

I want to find the similarity of words using the BERT model within the NER task. I have my own dataset so, I don't want to use the pre-trained model.
I do the following:

```
from transformers import BertModel
hidden_reps, cls_head = BertModel(token_ids , attention_mask = attn_mask , token_type_ids = seg_ids)
```

where

```
token_ids with Shape : [1, 4, 47]
attn_mask with Shape : [1, 4, 47]
seg_ids with Shape : [1, 4, 47]
```

but I have an error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-5fa632122cc7> in <module>()
      1 from transformers import BertModel
----> 2 hidden_reps, cls_head = BertModel(token_ids , attention_mask = attn_mask , token_type_ids = seg_ids)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attention_mask'
```

How can I fix this error??

and how can I find the word embedding and the similarity of a given word using this model?

I could not find any tutorials or similar codes for this task.

Comment: note that BERT is designed to assign embeddings to words in the context while Word2Vec or GloVe doesn't need a context.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I think you are confused with `pretrained` and `finetuned`.

BERT is `pretrained` on a lot of text data. By using this `pretrained` BERT, you have a model that already have knowledge about text.

BERT can then be `finetuned` on specific dataset, where BERT learn specific knowledge related to the dataset. That's why a finetuned BERT is bad on other datasets : the knowledge does not apply.

You have a custom dataset. So you don't want to use a `finetuned` model, but you want to still use a `pretrained` model (to have access to the general knowledge of BERT).

If you use a BERT model from scratch (not `pretrained`), you're basically creating an empty model, randomly initialized : it's **useless**.

---

Now that we have clarified this, let's see your problem.

What you are doing is calling the constructor of `BertModel` with the arguments of the `forward` pass. You first need to create the model, and then use the `forward` pass :

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig
config = BertConfig(...)    # Here your parameters to initialize your BERT as you want, such as number of heads, etc...
model = BertModel(config)
hidden_reps, cls_head = model(token_ids, attention_mask=attn_mask, token_type_ids=seg_ids)
```

---

**BUT**, as I explained in the first part, you should not do this : it's completely useless and your results are going to be random. You want to use a `pretrained` BERT, to have some meaningful results :

```
from transformers import BertModel
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
hidden_reps, cls_head = model(token_ids, attention_mask=attn_mask, token_type_ids=seg_ids)
```

*Note : Your results can be improved further if you `finetune` your BERT model on your custom dataset.*

---

Final point : **Don't reinvent the wheel**

People already tried to use BERT for word similarity. Instead of implementing this from scratch, using only a `pretrained` model, potentially adding bug to your own implementation, just use some already existing code !

I'm not sure about NER, but for word similarity, you can take a look at [BERT Score](https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score). Their model is already finetuned for word similarity, so it's likely that you will get higher score using this approach, and also much easier path to take.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use BERT Score for work similarity? Based on what I read, it seems BERT Score only can be used for sentence similarity.

Answer (score 0):

If obtaining word similarity is your main goal, I would suggest you to look at [Word2Vec from genism](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html).

You can even train a simple network on your corpus and fetch the most similar word(vectors).

Comment: I want to see the result in BERT, and then make a comparison among some models.